# Adding fields to Django form dynamically (and cleanly)

Tags: django, forms, dynamic

Hey guys, I know this question has been brought up numerous times, but I'm not quite getting the full implementation. As you can see below, I've got a form that I can dynamically tell how many rows to create. **How can I create an "Add Row" link that tells the view how many rows to create?** I would really like to do it without augmenting the url...

```
# views.py
def myView(request):
    if request.method == "POST": 
        form = MyForm(request.POST, num_rows=1)

        if form.is_valid():
            return render_to_response('myform_result.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        form = MyForm(num_rows=1)

    return render_to_response('myform.html', {'form':form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))


# forms.py
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        num_rows = kwargs.pop('num_rows',1)
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for row in range(0, num_rows):
            field = forms.CharField(label="Row")
            self.fields[str(row)] = field


# myform.html  http://example.com/myform
<form action="." method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <ul>
        {% for field in form %}
            <li style="margin-top:.25em">
                <span class="normal">{{ field.label }}</span> 
                {{ field }}
                <span class="formError">{{ field.errors }}</span>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
<a href="ADD_ANOTHER_ROW?">+ Add Row</a>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you have a form with a variable number of rows, what you need is a [formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/formsets/).

Comment: Awesome, I knew it was something I probably hadn't gotten into before. Thanks for steering me in the right direction! Besides formsets working better than what I was doing, the `ManagementForm` is the part I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

11 years later!!!

I wanted to add a -not-so-important flag to the form dynamically without creatig a specific form for this task. Here's how i handled my case

```
class CreateFooView(generic.CreateView):  
   ... 
   def get_form(self, form_class=None):
       form = super().get_form(form_class=self.form_class)
       ...
       field = forms.BooleanField(label="Add to Bar",required=False)
       form.fields['add_to_bar'] = field
       return form
```