# Django - Add field to form dynamically

Tags: jquery, python, django, forms

**Objective:**
Add a field to a form dynamically by pressing a button. Once submitted, store those values from all the fields in a list.

*(I have already looked at other questions on Stack Overflow and tried to find a basic tutorial/explanation how to do this: [dynamically add field to a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142025/dynamically-add-field-to-a-form))*

I am not sure what I need to be looking up/researching. I understand it will involve JavaScript but its the Django side that I am unsure how it will work.

I have created a basic form for starters:

[image]

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class SimpleForm(models.Model):
    basic_field = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

**Forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from models import SimpleForm

class SimpleForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = SimpleForm
    fields = ['basic_field']
```

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from forms import SimpleForm

def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        # For loop to iterate over dynamically created fields
        # Store values in list
    else:
        form = SimpleForm()
    return render(request, "index.html", {'form':form})
```

**Index.html**

```
{% block content %}
    <h1>Simple Form</h1>
    <form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="button" class="btn-default">Add Another Field</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Use jQuery or javascript to add fields to the form (you could give them all a common class name). On clicking submit, capture the event in your own event handler, prevent the default action and convert values from all your fields into a list or JSON object. Pass this to your server and everything else is business as usual!

Comment: Heres a question where the god himself has answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942359/adding-fields-to-django-form-dynamically-and-cleanly

Answer (score 7):

Try using [django-formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/formsets/). You can start with this neat [tutorial](http://whoisnicoleharris.com/2015/01/06/implementing-django-formsets.html).

Basically ,what you need to do is create a formset out of your forms in your views.py.

```
    from django.forms.formsets import formset_factory
    CompoundFormset = formset_factory(SimpleForm,max_num=10,extra=1)
```